# Filtering over array inside object javascript

Tags: javascript, filter

Maybe it's Friday morning and I'm having a moment but cant see why this isn't working.

I have this JSON

```
var recipes = [{
            name: "Beef Lasagne",
            ingredients: [
                "mince",
                "pasta",
                "sauce",
                "tomatoes"
            ]}]
```

I can do this: `recipes.filter(recipe => recipe.name.includes('e'))` and it filters correctly

however when I try and do this: `recipes.filter(recipe => recipe.ingredients.includes('e'))`

I get I'm trying to filter a string in ex1 and then in ex2 im filter an array, what else do I need to do to get the filter in the second one working?

Comment: You cannot filter an array like that `recipe.ingredients.includes('e')` - you need to add a filter to that array too or add an ingredient that is just "e"

Comment: `String.includes()` will look for a specific string inside another string. `Array.includes()` will look for the exact element. So `recipe.ingredients.includes('e')` only works if the string `'e'` is part of the ingredients. Are you trying to search if any of the ingredients has the letter 'e' in it?

Comment: @Shilly yes exactly

Comment: @Shilly you should transfer that comment to an answer.

Comment: what's your expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Array.includes()` will look for a specific element. Since ingredients is an array as well, you need to loop over the ingredients array as well.

So as written, it'll only work if ingredients equals:

```
    ingredients: [
        "mince",
        "pasta",
        "sauce",
        "tomatoes",
        "e"
    ]
```

So you probably want something like:

```
recipes.filter( recipe => recipe.ingredients.some( ingredient => ingredient.includes( 'e' ) ) );
```

```js
var recipes = [{
    name: "Beef Lasagne",
    ingredients: [
      "mince",
      "pasta",
      "sauce",
      "tomatoes"
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Beef Lasagne without e",
    ingredients: [
      "minc",
      "past",
      "tomatos"
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Beef Lasagne with sauce and no mince",
    ingredients: [
      "sauce",
      "pasta",
      "tomatoes"
    ]
  }
]

console.log(
    recipes.filter( recipe => recipe.ingredients.some( ingredient => ingredient.includes( 'e' ) ) )
)
console.log(
    recipes.filter( recipe => recipe.ingredients.some( ingredient => ingredient.startsWith( 'min' ) ) )
)
```

Comment: yes this is what I want! this allows me to change the string method, i.e. from `includes` to `startsWith`. thanks!

Comment: You can use any array method this way to map/filter/reduce specific fields. If you use a library like lodash or underscore, they will have builtin versions of these as well.

Comment: sure. i like this method coz it's expandable. and yeh ive used underscore before but try and stay away from librarys when learning :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `.join("")` on the Array to convert it to a String and be able to use `.includes()` the way you initially wanted:

```js
var recipes = [
  {
    name: "Beef Lasagne",
    ingredients: [
      "mince",
      "pasta",
      "sauce",
      "tomatoes"
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Raw Pasta",
    ingredients: [
      "pasta"
    ]
  }
];

recipes = recipes.filter(recipe => recipe.ingredients.join("").includes('e'));

console.log(recipes);
```

Comment: ok yes this works I guess but what if wanted to change my filter so that I could say `startsWith()` instead. so only return me recipes where the ingredients startWith..

Comment: @thewalrus Do you mean the ingredients have to start with 'e'? All of them or some of them?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
recipes.filter(recipe => recipe.ingredients.filter(ingredient => ingredient.includes('e')).length > 0)
```